# custom dialog with radio button and textview android

Tags: android, listview, radio-button, customdialog

I have a radio button and textview in the custom dialog. It has around 250 items so I am using list view.
  I am setting OnCheckedStateListener on the radio button and whenever the state chagnes I dismiss the dialog in listener. And I am setting one item as checkedby default. 
But whenever I open the dialog for second time, OnCheckedStateListener is being called before the dialog opens up and the whole application gets crashed.
 I am following holder view pattern. Can someone please suggest me the right approach to use view holder pattern in this scenario with some sample code or can you please point out any good material on web.
    I have search a lot before posting this question. But nothing was helpful.
  
 Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I have tried with `onclickListener` also, but it was not working sometimes when I select the top most or bottom one in the visible view of dialog ... strange..
 same with `onFocusChangeListener` as well.

EDIT:

```
     if (row == null) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

        holder = new RecordHolder();
        holder.txtTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        holder.radiobutton = (RadioButton)row.findViewById(R.id.radiobutton);               

            holder.radiobutton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new 
                                       CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, 
                                            boolean isChecked) {
            if(buttonView.isChecked()){
                       // this call back listener will dismiss the dialog 
                       // from the fragement where I have called
            mCallbackListnr.stateUpdated(pPosition);

                        }


                }}); 



                row.setTag(holder);
            } else {
                holder = (RecordHolder) row.getTag();
            }

            Item item = data.get(position);
                // i am setting the state as checked here

            if(item.id.equals(selectedItem.id)){
              holder.radiobutton.setChecked(true);
            }else{
                 holder.radiobutton.setChecked(false);  
            }
            holder.txtTitle.setText(item.getTitle());

    }
```

Comment: Where do you have the `OnCheckedStateListener`? It would be useful if you posted some code...

Comment: I am setting the listener if the content view is null. Sorry, unfortunately i am not allowed to upload any code into web hmmmm..

Comment: @Szymon, I have added sample code. Can you please suggest the changes that has to be done here.

Comment: What is the error? Can you post logcat?